# Sql to hibernate (nested query with group by)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to convert my sql query into hibernate query

```
 select * from user_projects where endDate is not null and startDate is not null and soft_delete=? and startDate<=? and 
endDate>=? and endDate<=? and (endDate,user_id) in (select MAX(endDate),user_id from user_projects  
where soft_delete=? group by user_id) ;
```

I converted it into hibernate code.
This is my hibernate code is

```
        List<Staffing> staffing = null;
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
        String dateString = df.format(duration);
            Date date = df.parse(dateString);

        DetachedCriteria maxDate=DetachedCriteria.forClass(Staffing.class);
        maxDate.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.groupProperty("user")).add(Projections.max("endDate"),"maxDate"));
        Criteria criteria = getCriteria();

        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("startDate")).add(Restrictions.le("startDate", new Date()));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("endDate")).add(Restrictions.ge("endDate", new Date()));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("softDelete", false));

        criteria.add(Subqueries.le(date, maxDate));
        staffing = criteria.list();
        return staffing;
```

But I am getting list of object array .Can anyone please help me to convert it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hello You can try using result transformers like this

criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(user_projects.class));

But the names of the properties returned  from the sql query has to be the same as the property names in user_projects.class